# Displaying large GridView's efficienty in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My web application I am creating features a lot of grids, and one baffling requirement is that it needs to be able to show a GridView, which sometimes has over 1000 rows, all without paging and in within one scrollable panel. The column count is also large, with around 20 on there.

The query isn't too slow, but the slowness seems to come from the gigantic size of the HTML source being displayed. Are there any methods of reducing the size of the source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Davide mentioned, paging is essential. If server resources are cheap, you could consider
1) Removing whitespace from the html using a response filter. There are standard modules available. A quick search leads to [sample module](http://madskristensen.net/post/A-whitespace-removal-HTTP-module-for-ASPNET-20.aspx)
2) Enable gzip compression on IIS for dynamic content

But, the slowness may not be due to the size of the html. Some other things to watch out for:
1) Inefficient Javascript manipulating the DOM, esp on document load\ready. 
2) Enabling caching headers for static resources (these are turned by default on IIS)

Answer (score 0):

in the MVC version Telerik grid supports ajax scrolling which allows to show more records on demand when scrolling down.

I am surprised from your requirements, it is anyway a bad idea to show all records at once, what if you get 10 millions records? I would implement paging and show 1 page at time, eventually with a page size of 500 but still with it!